# Mockito/Powermock not working as expected with Kotlin

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, mockito, kotlin, powermock

I'm using mockito/powermock version 1.7.0, Spring Boot 2.0.0 M2, Kotlin 1.3.0.

I'm testing a Spring `@Service` class, that inject a Repository.
I want to mock that repository on my tests, so I can just test the class itself.

I'm new to Kotlin, but I come from Java, so I tried doing this "the java way", but probably I'm missing something...

Here is my Service interface:

```
interface MyService {
    fun create(myObject: MyObject): MyObject
}
```

... and its implementation:

```
@Service
class DefaultMyService : MyService {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository
    override fun create(myObject: MyObject): MyObject = this.myRepository.insert(myObject)
}
```

Here is my repository (I'm using Spring Data with Mongo):

```
interface MyRepository: MongoRepository<MyObject, String>
```

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(MyService::class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository
    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var myService: MyService

    @Test
    fun shouldDoSomething() {
        val myObject = MyObject(name = "Marco")
        `when`(myRepository.insert(myObject)).thenReturn(myObject)
        assertEquals(myObject.name, this.myService.create(myObject).name)
    }
}
```

When I run this test, an exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:260)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.getInstanceForClassLoader(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:41)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.create(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:35)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 16 more
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it's an issue with some configuration, but I can't understand exactly where the mistake is.

Comment: What version of PowerMock and Mockito are you using? It also looks like it's unnecessary to use PowerMock in this example, when you can use kotlin-allopen, or this http://hadihariri.com/2016/10/04/Mocking-Kotlin-With-Mockito/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that your mockito and powermock versions are not working very well together. You have to use versions which are compatible. See the compatibility matrix of powermock https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Latest compatible is Mockito: `2.8.x`   with PowerMock: `1.7.0`